# Best way to fill up a Cassandra Database

Tags: cassandra

I am looking at the best way to pre fill a cassandra database using a custom table.
Is there any method to insert lets say 100GB of data, other than using for example cassandra-stress ?
This is just for a POC, no real dat.
What I want to achieve is to have 2 data sets, one with 50GB of Data and the other with 100GB.

It can be dummy data.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Besides `cassandra-stress` there are better tools:

- [NoSQLBench](http://nosqlbench.io/) - initially developed inside DataStax for load testing, it's now open source. It's very flexible & performant.  It includes several built-in workloads that you can use
- [tlp-stress](https://thelastpickle.com/tlp-stress/) - provides several built-in workloads, and is also quite performant.

In both cases, the size of the data on disk will depend on the data itself - because data is compressed, it depends on the data structure on how good they are compressed.

Comment: Thank you Alex ! I will have a look at those tools